# What might be the problem with my adapter i seem not to find it``

Tags: java, android

The view seems not to bind to the ArrayList(ie private  ArrayList mEvents;) that  i passed to the class ,on the onBindViewHolder(ie  holder.mTextView2.setText(current.getcity());) i can seem to access the textView variables(ie  public TextView mTextview2;), that i declared in the view holder class. I have tried to make the variables as a member variable but it seems not to work well

```
public class eventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private  ArrayList<recycleview_items> mEvents;

    public eventsAdapter(ArrayList<recycleview_items> passedArray){
        //constructor for the adapter calls for which i created
        mEvents = passedArray;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //we pass the layout of our card to the adapter here
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycle_listitem, parent, false);
        eventViewHolder events = new eventViewHolder(v);
        return  events;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //we pass data from the array list we created  to the views
        recycleview_items current = mEvents.get(position);

        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(current.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(current.getname());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(current.getcity());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mEvents.size();
    };

    public static class eventViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView mImageview ;
        public TextView mTextview;
        public TextView mTextview2;

        public eventViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
            mTextview =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
            mTextview2 =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the problem ?

Comment: i cant access the mtextview, mImageView variables from the onBindViewHolder method

Comment: try casting like eventViewHolder eventHolder = (eventViewHolder) holder;
eventHolder.mTextView2.setText(current.getcity());

Answer (score 0):

```
public class eventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private  ArrayList<recycleview_items> mEvents;

public eventsAdapter(ArrayList<recycleview_items> passedArray){
    //constructor for the adapter calls for which i created
    mEvents = passedArray;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //we pass the layout of our card to the adapter here
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycle_listitem, parent, false);
    eventViewHolder events = new eventViewHolder(v);
    return  events;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //we pass data from the array list we created  to the views
    recycleview_items current = mEvents.get(position);
    holder.bind(current);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mEvents.size();
};
class eventViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public ImageView mImageview ;
    public TextView mTextview;
    public TextView mTextview2;

    public eventViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
        mTextview =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
        mTextview2 =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view2);

      public void bind(recycleview_items item){
        //bind your items here
        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(item.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(item.getname());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(item.getcity());
    }
}
```

}

I've rewritten your code for you with slight modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You should create adapter like this

```
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<eventsAdapter.eventViewHolder >
```

Also you should edit

```
public eventViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder
```

And

```
onBindViewHolder(eventViewHolder holder, int position)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  public class eventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<eventsAdapter.eventViewHolder>{
private  ArrayList<recycleview_items> mEvents;

public eventsAdapter(ArrayList<recycleview_items> passedArray){
    //constructor for the adapter calls for which i created
    mEvents = passedArray;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public eventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycle_listitem, parent, false);
    return  new eventViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull eventViewHolder holder, int position) {
    recycleview_items current = mEvents.get(position);
    holder.mImageview.setImageResource(current.getImageResource());
    holder.mTextview.setText(current.getname());
    holder.mTextview2.setText(current.getcity());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}


class eventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 ImageView mImageview;
 TextView mTextview;
 TextView mTextview2;

public eventViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mImageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
    mTextview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
    mTextview2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
   }
  }
}
```

Almost every thing was in Your code that's i have done some modification.

Answer (score 0):

Mate see your Holder View Class name its 'eventViewHolder' and for onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder you're accessing the Recycler.ViewHolder so it's very obvious that you can't access those variable just change this..

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull eventsAdapter.eventViewHolder holder, int position) {
.....    
}
```

and in

```
@NonNull
@Override
public eventsAdapter.eventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
 ......
}
```